# How can we test functions that aren't exposed when building R packages?

Tags: unit-testing, r, tdd

I'm currently developing a [graphical analysis package](https://github.com/briandk/granova/commits/dev) for R. We're trying to use principles from both [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) and [Test-Driven Development](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Testing) (TDD). But, we've run into a conceptual problem.

#### How can you test unexposed functions?

Consider the following simplified example. `Outer()` is a function we're building in our [package](https://github.com/briandk/granova/commits/dev), and we expose it to users by listing it in the [`NAMESPACE`](https://github.com/briandk/granova/blob/dev/NAMESPACE) file. `Inner()` is a short (~5 line) utility function:

```
Outer <- function(...) {

  Inner <- function(...) {
    return(x)
  }

  return( Inner() )
}
```

Most of the user-exposed functions in our [package](https://github.com/briandk/granova/commits/dev) are collections of short, single-behavior `Inner()` style functions that lie under the umbrella of a single `Outer()` function the user can call. [`Granova.ds.ggplot()`](https://github.com/briandk/granova/blob/dev/R/granova.ds.ggplot.R) is one example. Such a modular design is strongly advocated by [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), and we're quite happy with the results. But we don't know how to build unit tests for it, since the functions we want to test aren't accessible outside the scope of the `Granova.ds.ggplot()` function given how we designed it.

Several ideas/solutions occurred to us:

1. Tests should only have access to public APIs. Since functions like `Inner()` are by design not public (they're not exported in `NAMESPACE`) we shouldn't even be trying to test them.
2. Hadley Wickham's `testthat` [package wiki](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Testing) says it supports testing of "non-exported functions" using an `R CMD check` workflow.
3. If all else fails, we could somehow manually break our `Outer()` functions for testing purposes

#### None of these solutions has worked so far

Solution 1 seems like a cop-out. We believe that especially in R, it's sensible to have a top-level function that calls various short, single-responsibility utility methods. Not being able to test such methods seems silly, and like the type of thing there's a solution for but we just haven't found yet.

Solution 2 might work, but we haven't gotten it to work so far. If you try cloning [our repository](https://github.com/briandk/granova/commits/dev), then sourcing `inst/dev.R` I believe you'll find in the test output that it cannot find the function `InitializeGgplot()`, even though [said function](https://github.com/briandk/granova/blob/dev/R/granova.1w.ggplot.R) is defined in lines 613-615 of [`granova.1w.ggplot()`](https://github.com/briandk/granova/blob/dev/R/granova.1w.ggplot.R). Similarly, running `R CMD check` at the terminal doesn't seem to execute any of our tests at all. It does take a great deal of time and throw insulting errors at us, though :-(

Solution 3 is in a sense pragmatic, but counter to the aim of always moving toward a goal state of the project. It doesn't make sense to us.

#### What would be the ideal solution

Ideally, we're looking for a way to leverage a package like `testthat` to rapidly provide feedback as we code, and to allow us to test functions like `Inner()` that exist *within* functions like `Outer()`. Even better would be a way to do it without resorting to `R CMD check`, which due to the 3-d complexity of some of our functions takes almost a full minute to run each time.

So, what are we missing? Should TDD practices allow for testing Outer/Inner style setups in R? If they do, how can we do so in developing our package? Any feedback is welcome, and I'll try to respond to anything that's unclear.

Thanks!

Comment: If your Inner functions are actually only defined _within_ the code for Outer, I believe these are only actually created when Outer is called. So I see no way of testing these then. For other, non-nested but non-exported functions, testing should be possible through getAnywhere and the likes.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "goal state of the project" in option 3?  I would break these inner functions out, but not expose them in the API (i.e. not export the function to NAMESPACE).  Thus you can document and test them and still have a clean API.

Comment: @Andrie - great question; I was unclear. One of our solutions involved a pseudo-version of your suggestion. We would intentionally break `Outer()` (say by commenting out its function declaration) to force the `Inner()` functions to be top-level. Later, we'd uncomment out the lines. To me, that felt like moving away from a goal state, because it meant deliberately breaking an exposed function *now* and having to remember to unbreak it again *later* before we build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `Inner` implements non-trivial functionality that you want to test, I'd suggest moving `Inner` to the top-level, but not exporting it.  Generally, I avoid nesting functions within other functions for exactly this reason - they're hard to test.

You can test during development with the usual testthat functions because you're probably just sourcing in all your R code and not worrying about namespaces (at least that's how I develop).  You then use `R CMD check` in conjunction with `test_package` to ensure the tests still work at build time - `test_packages` runs the tests in the package namespace so they can test non-exported functions.

Comment: is your general suggestion more like Model 1: http://www.cl.ly/0D1k341b1o3J3S3A3o32 or like Model 2: http://www.cl.ly/2Y3g3p1045002B1K3X18 ? Also, in the case of either model, what do I need to write/include in either my build script or my /tests file to make sure test code can exercise the Inner() functions?

Comment: OK, I think I just figured it out. It's probably simplest to aggregate similar functions together, at top level, into a single file. Then, I can just have a script that calls `library(testthat)`, sources the files that contains the functions, and calls `test_file()` for each file of tests. Sorry!

Comment: Yes and see my devtools package on github for functions that automate that process

Comment: @hadley do you have a simple example of this I could look at? Would be handy.

Answer (score 6):

IMO there is no problem here -- Inner is just a nondetachable part of Outer, so testing Outer tests Inner. Would you be willing to test anonymous functions? Same here.

Comment: In my case non-exported functions are non-trivial. There are more moving parts than a typical anonymous function, so testing is useful.